# Which is correct: “to scrape” or “to scraped”?

Tags: tenses, infinitives

When playing he tripped which caused him to _____ the skin away from his knee.
scrape or scraped, I am confusing about tense.

Comment: Which would you think is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you see "to" before a verb it's telling you it's an infinitive so the question of tense doesn't come into consideration.  The infinitive is formed by putting "to" before the verb.  In this case it should be "caused him to scrape the skin away".

Answer (score 0):

There is no tense. This is the infinitive, which has no tense. So the correct form is "scrape".